# Why Foreign key not inserted in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

i have two entities. Employee and address. relation between this entities is @OneToOne. when i want to insert into db the foreign key not be insert into table. 
my entity are:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="Address")
  public class Address{

  @Id
  @Column(name="Id")
  private int Id;

 @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="emp_id", 
        insertable=true, updatable=false, 
        nullable=true)
 private Employee  employee ;
```

and employee entity

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
 public class Employee{

@Id 
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="emp_id")
private int emp_id;


@OneToOne(fetch =FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="emp_id", 
       insertable=true, updatable=false, 
       nullable=true)
private Address address;
```

and code for add employee

```
Employee employee = new Employee("john" , ... );
Address address = new Address("USA" , ...);
employee.setAddress(address);
address.setEmployee(employee);
employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
```

Should foreign keys in database tables is specified ?

Comment: you re missing the @ManyToOne for the foreign key

Comment: @indian did not understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: could you share you DB table structure?

Comment: it work correctly. thanks for your Attentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need `@JoinColumn` on the owning side of a relationship. So, if in database you have foreign key from `Address` table, column `emp_id` to `Employee` table, column `id`, the mapping should look like this

**Address**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Address")
public class Address {

    ...

   @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="emp_id", 
        insertable=true, updatable=false, 
        nullable=true)
   private Employee  employee ;
```

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee{

    ...

    @OneToOne(fetch =FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
    private Address address;
```