# Generate database using hibernate annontation (foreign key not found)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I am trying to create OneToOne relation using Hiberate/JPA between two classes Stock and StockDetails, so when i generate the database I'm not seeing the foreign key in the StockDetail table that should reference Stock, this is my codes :

Stock Classe :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock", catalog = "migration")
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer Stock_Id;
    private StockDetail stockDetail;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Stock_Id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getStock_Id() {
        return this.Stock_Id;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stock", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public StockDetail getStockDetail() {
        return this.stockDetail;
    }

}
```

StockDetail  Classe :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "detail_stock", catalog = "migration")
public class StockDetail implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer Stock_Id;
    private Stock stock;

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", 
    parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "stock"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "Stock_Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getStock_Id() {
        return this.Stock_Id;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Stock getStock() {
        return this.stock;
    }

}
```

I found one topic about the same issue, but it didn't resolve my probleme:

[Why Foreign key not inserted in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840750/why-foreign-key-not-inserted-in-hibernate)

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't find the foreign key"? What do you expect to find in the generated table, and what do you find instead?

Comment: I'm not seeing the foreign key in the StockDetail table that should reference Stock.

Comment: What do you think `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` means? Read [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html).

Comment: i didn't find the solution !! could just help me !!

Comment: What isn't clear in *"it may be used in a OneToOne mapping in which the primary key of the referencing entity is used as a foreign key to the referenced entity"*? The primary key **is** the foreign key. So of course there is no other column. The stock detail identified by 123 is the detaill of the stock identified by 123. Why are you using an annotation if you don't even know what it's used for?

Comment: Look i know that Stock_Id is the primary key for stock table , it is also the foreign and primary in same time is StockDetails.

Comment: What's your question then?

Comment: im just a beginner i followed some tutorial to understand Hibernate/JPA.

Comment: my question is : Could you correct my codes to generate correctly the schema ,so  i have to find that Stock_id in StockDetail Table reference Stock Table

Comment: You just said that you understood that the primary key in StockDetails ALSO WAS a foreign key to Stock.id. So it DOES reference Stock. To know the stock of a stockdetails, you look at its ID: it's also the ID of the stock. There is nothing to correct.

Comment: yes but i found no reference in StockDetails Table !

Comment: We're turning in circle here. What do you expect to find in the stockdetails table that isn't already there? Is that a foreign key **constraint** on the stockdetail.stock_id column? If so use the `@ForeignKey` annotation. If what you expect to find is an additional column referencing stock_id, then you don't need one.

Comment: hh Okéy, i expect to find in StockDetails table a primary key = foreing key (reference Stock table), so i find that Sock_Id in StockDetails  as primary key but not as a foreign key in the same time

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html?is-external=true

Answer (score 0):

You got to do something like this in StockDetail

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "detail_stock", catalog = "migration")
public class StockDetail implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer stockDetailId;
    private Stock stock;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Stock getStock() {
        return this.stock;
    }

    /**
     * @param stock
     *            the stock to set
     */
    public void setStock(Stock stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    /**
     * @return the stockDetailId
     */
    @Id
    public Integer getStockDetailId() {
        return stockDetailId;
    }

    /**
     * @param stockDetailId the stockDetailId to set
     */
    public void setStockDetailId(Integer stockDetailId) {
        this.stockDetailId = stockDetailId;
    }

}
```

The issue with your configuration is that you are trying to make stock_id as primary key of stock_detail with the following configuration.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "Stock_Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
```

Instead what you should do is have a stock_detail_id as primary key of stock_details. Since you have a bi-directional one-to-one mapping between both the entities hibernate will automatically generate the foreign key with above mapping.

Comment: So stockDetailId will be as a foreign key ?

Comment: It would be the primary key.

Comment: So we must have relationship with Stock and StockDetails Using a foreign key (StockId)

Comment: Thats right. A foreign key in database establishes a bi-directional relation the way you have attempted in the hibernate mapping.

Comment: So When i test your correction i find that stockDetailId is a primary key but not a foreign key to reference stock Table

Comment: That is what i have said in my comment that stockDetailId will be the primary key while stock_id will be foreign key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81077/discussion-between-johnson-abraham-and-ahmed-net).